# Can anyone have a house plot or they have set a limit?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I was wondering if I need to act fast and stack up some cash for a house because I don't know if the game have set a limit on the server for housing. Like did they set a limit of 100 000 houses all around the world in-game or everyone could have a house plot and don't have to worry for a space left.

I remember playing Ultima Online and the world went full and no place was left to place a house plot, we had to find someone who was selling it. Good old time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the only housing available in the game must be purchased on a free company (guild) basis, and aren't available to individuals.†

That being said, there are multiple instances of each residental zone, but not an infinite number of instances. Depending on your server's population, you may or may not have open plots in the zone of your choice, but odds are good that there's some open plots *somewhere* if you're not picky about location. Periodically, the dev team adds extra residential instances to the game, so in the future, more plots will be added if needed.

† Individual housing is said to be coming in the near future (patch 2.35-2.38), but isn't here yet. However, you can purchase a "personal room" in your Free Company's estate (if they own one) for 300,000 gil.